# C++11: Storing an Iterator without knowing its container

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, std

Is there, in C++11, something along the line of an object of type `Iterator<T>` which just stores an iterator without knowing what std container the iterator stems from, only the type of data the container stores?

If such an object does not exist, what is the reason for it's absence?

Comment: How could an iterator work without knowing the structure of the container? If you want to be able to navigate (++ etc) then the structure must be known. If you don't need to navigate then what you are talking about is a _pointer_.

Comment: @davmac Well I was thinking something along the line of polymorphism, where you have an abstract class Iterator which provides functions such as increment, comparison and dereferencing. How each of those functions is implemented then depends on the concrete type of iterator

Comment: Then the answer is "no, because there is no need for it, and if all iterators had virtual functions it would hurt performance".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no base class for iterators in C++, since they are designed for high performance (so no virtual calls are welcomed).

All iterators types are resolved in compile time and all "iterator storages" types also have to be resolved in compile time.

What is your use case? There might be another, better solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no common iterator base class and type erasure workarounds (if even possible in this case) would only defer the need to store the type somewhere else somehow.

Maybe you should rethink what it is you are trying to achieve and ask a question about that?